# Can an Ember.js Route redirect to an external URL?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

If I want to have a URL on an Ember.js website called example1.com that forwards to a URL on example2.com, how would I do that.  Can I create a route of example1.com that will perform the forward to example2.com - maybe in the beforeModel hook?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a simple href?  What are your limitations that make this ember specific?

Comment: It doesn't need to be Ember-specific, but it's not a link.  If I enter a URL in the browser address bar for http://example1.com/page1 (which happens to be an Ember.js app), it needs to forward automatically to http://example2.com/page2.

Answer (score 17):

Just use a regular `<a>`:

```
<a href="example2.com">Route to Example 2</a>
```

If you want to have it forward if the user types in the URL directly into the address bar, you will need to do that redirect in your server. That doesn't have anything to do with Ember though.

Alternatively you could just use

```
App.YourRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
     window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
  }
});
```

The `beforeModel` (or any other) hook should also work.

Answer (score 12):

In any hook, use:

```
window.location.replace("example2.com");
```